# How to select an image on the J2ME Canvas

Tags: java, graphics-programming, html-canvas, image

I am working on J2ME. I have got a canvas, with a layout of a Checkers board. At the position of pieces, I have placed images. The point at which I got stuck is, how to select/highlite a piece's image for a move. I can't figure out the appropriate commandListener and how to handle this keyPressedEvent.
I understood the logic of this game from:
[Draughts AI](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/16135/how-to-implement-a-i-for-checkers-draughts)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's always an array like DS representing the chess, always a current position, always a target position. always highlight the current position. after press a button, you change the status of the chess, and then you select another position .....
basically what I suggested is you need to think in state machine based model.